# sample Rails Application that includes email support page with captcha

Tags: ruby-on-rails, captcha

What's the quickest / easiest starting point for a simple Rails application that has a main page, and an email "contact us" page, with captcha support?  Is there a popular base Rails app that I could download that would already have this functionality as a starting point?

(e.g. for just a basic informational type web site, but with the abily for the user to send support requests back to support, but via a web page with captcha)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO you shouldn't use Rails, nor any other Framework for a task like that. For a simple contact form you could put a standalone php page plus some static html pages on your server and you're done.

If you doesn't know Rails yet (or any other web framework written in any language) it would be a pain to setup a such structure only to display a contact form. Is like to take a gun to kill a fly.

BTW to come to your question, I don't know any project which do what you're asking for, maybe you want to try to do that by yourself, it's pretty simple, what you need is [ActionMailer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) and a [captcha plugin](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha)

Just my two cents.

Comment: thanks Fabio - sounds like there may not be anything out there matching exactly what I'm after...

Comment: I think so, for the reasons I've written.